# Merge two data frames on three columns in Python

Tags: python, pandas

I have two data frames and I would like to merge them on the two columns Latitude and Longitude. The resulting df should include all columns.
df1:

```
            Date  Latitude  Longitude        LST
0     2019-01-01     66.33     17.100  -8.010004
1     2019-01-09     66.33     17.100  -6.675005
2     2019-01-17     66.33     17.100 -21.845003
3     2019-01-25     66.33     17.100 -26.940004
4     2019-02-02     66.33     17.100 -23.035009
...   ...            ...       ...    ...
```

and df2:

```
     Station_Number       Date  Latitude  Longitude  Elevation      Value
0       CA002100636 2019-01-01   69.5667  -138.9167        1.0 -18.300000
1       CA002100636 2019-01-09   69.5667  -138.9167        1.0 -26.871429
2       CA002100636 2019-01-17   69.5667  -138.9167        1.0 -19.885714
3       CA002100636 2019-01-25   69.5667  -138.9167        1.0 -17.737500
4       CA002100636 2019-02-02   69.5667  -138.9167        1.0 -13.787500
...             ...        ...       ...        ...        ...        ...
```

I have tried: `LST_1=pd.merge(df1, df2, how = 'inner')` but using merge in that way I have lost several data points, which are included in both data frames.

Comment: try passing the `on` parameter in `merge()` method...for example `LST_1=pd.merge(df1, df2, how = 'inner',on=['Date','Longitude','Latitude'])`

Comment: Yea, I have tried that one already, but for some reason data is still being  lost while merging

Comment: Please provide a minimal reproducible example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example. Show the output you got, and explain why it is incorrect, and also include the expected output.

Comment: I think it's a bad idea to merge on float numbers... Do you try to multiple `Latitude` and `Longitude` by 10000, round and cast to `int`. `(43.577244, 7.055041)` => `np.round(43.577244 * 10000).astype(int), np.round(7.055041 * 10000).astype(int)` => `(435772, 70550)`.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if you want to merge on a specific column, if so you need to pick one with overlapping identifiers - for instance the "Date" column.

```
df_ = pd.merge(df1, df2, on="Date")
print(df_)
     Date  Latitude_x  Longitude_x  ... Longitude_y Elevation        Value
0  01.01.2019       66.33         17.1  ...    -138.9167       1.0  -18.300000
1  09.01.2019       66.33         17.1  ...    -138.9167       1.0  -26.871429
2  17.01.2019       66.33         17.1  ...    -138.9167       1.0  -19.885714
3  25.01.2019       66.33         17.1  ...    -138.9167       1.0  -17.737500
4  02.02.2019       66.33         17.1  ...    -138.9167       1.0  -13.787500

[5 rows x 9 columns]

<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 5 entries, 0 to 4
Data columns (total 9 columns):
 #   Column          Non-Null Count  Dtype  
---  ------          --------------  -----  
 0   Date            5 non-null      object 
 1   Latitude_x      5 non-null      float64
 2   Longitude_x     5 non-null      float64
 3   LST             5 non-null      object 
 4   Station_Number  5 non-null      object 
 5   Latitude_y      5 non-null      int64  
 6   Longitude_y     5 non-null      int64  
 7   Elevation       5 non-null      float64
 8   Value           5 non-null      object 

dtypes: float64(3), int64(2), object(4)
memory usage: 400.0+ bytes
```

As you have column names that are the same pandas will create _x and _y on Latitude and Longitude.

If you want all the columns and the data in one row is independent from the others, then you can use pd.concat. However, this will create some NaN values, due to missing data.

```
df_1 = pd.concat([df1, df2])
print(df_1)
         Date  Latitude  Longitude  ... Station_Number Elevation        Value
0  01.01.2019     66.33       17.1  ...            NaN       NaN          NaN
1  09.01.2019     66.33       17.1  ...            NaN       NaN          NaN
2  17.01.2019     66.33       17.1  ...            NaN       NaN          NaN
3  25.01.2019     66.33       17.1  ...            NaN       NaN          NaN
4  02.02.2019     66.33       17.1  ...            NaN       NaN          NaN
0  01.01.2019     69.56  -138.9167  ...    CA002100636       1.0   -18.300000
1  09.01.2019     69.56  -138.9167  ...    CA002100636       1.0   -26.871429
2  17.01.2019     69.56  -138.9167  ...    CA002100636       1.0   -19.885714
3  25.01.2019     69.56  -138.9167  ...    CA002100636       1.0   -17.737500
4  02.02.2019     69.56  -138.9167  ...    CA002100636       1.0   -13.787500

df_1.info()
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 10 entries, 0 to 4
Data columns (total 7 columns):
 #   Column          Non-Null Count  Dtype  
---  ------          --------------  -----  
 0   Date            10 non-null     object 
 1   Latitude        10 non-null     float64
 2   Longitude       10 non-null     float64
 3   LST             5 non-null      object 
 4   Station_Number  5 non-null      object 
 5   Elevation       5 non-null      float64
 6   Value           5 non-null      object 
dtypes: float64(3), object(4)
memory usage: 640.0+ bytes
```